# Postgres restore through Lazarus Pascal doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, freepascal, lazarus

I'm building an application using Lazarus Pascal + Postgres on Ubuntu 12.04.

The following line of code works fine form the terminal:

```
/usr/bin/psql --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --quiet "dbHRS" < "t2"
```

However, it doesn't seem to run from within my Pascal program.

The restore lines are stored in a text file like this:

> /usr/bin/psql
>   --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --quiet "dbHRS" < "%s"

My Pascal code takes the two lines and replaces the `%s` with the actual file name and runs it like this:

```
    AssignFile(RPath, 'restore.inf'); //Name of text file
    Reset(RPath);
    xx:= 0; //just a dummy value. If it changes due to an error, it's easy to know

    Readln(RPath, FileString);
    ExecProgram:= FileString;

    Readln(RPath, FileString);
    ExecParams:= Format(FileString, [txtOpenName.Text]);

    CloseFile(RPath);
    ShowMessage('"' + ExecProgram + '"'); //shows correctly
    ShowMessage('"' + ExecParams + '"'); //shows correctly
    try
      ExecStatus := SysUtils.ExecuteProcess(UTF8ToSys(ExecProgram), ExecParams, []);

    Except
      on EOSError do xx:= ExecStatus; //This never occurs
    end;
```

ExecStatus is 0 and xx is is still 5. So I assume there are no errors.

What could be wrong? Why is the data not coming back into the database? The tables are empty, which means that the restore didn't happen.

BTW, I also have a back-up script in a similar way and it works fine. The data is correct. This is how I created the backup file.

Any assistants on this is greatly values.
Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFO:
I **can** run the following command using ExecuteProcess:

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump

--host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --role "mizk" --no-password  --format plain --data-only --inserts --column-inserts --verbose --file "abc" "dbHRS"
```

The above 2 lines indicate the ExecProgram and ExecParams used. So this is why I'm puzzled by the issue at hand.

Comment: 1. Check ExecStatus even if the try works - what is it? 2. Write a dummy shell-script that just logs its arguments to a file and call that instead to check all is ok on that end.

Comment: Testing with shells can be deceiving. Never recommend testing with shell, if the call used might not spawn a shell. It will confuse people only more.

Comment: @RichardHuxton ExecStatus returns 0

Comment: @RichardHuxton What do you mean by *logging its arguments*? I've printed the values using `ShowMessage` and they show up exactly the way they should.

Comment: I'm puzzled because I have a backup routine that works fin with the same ExecuteProcess. It works just fine. Of course it calls `/usr/bin/pg_dump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executeprocess executes using execve(2), and thus only runs a program + parameters, not a full shell with redirection.

So the pipe-in construct won't work, and probably the quoting is also wrong. (since these quotes won't be stripped and will be passed to the receiving program).

For unix specific shell use, use unix.fpsystem() which is system(3) alike.

Alternately, you could do something like

```
    s:=ExecProgram+' ' +ExecParams;
    ExecStatus:=Executeprocess ('/bin/sh',['-c',s]);
```

It's been a while since I wrote executeprocess  (2004-2005?), but afaik it does not raise exceptions as a part of normal usage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I chose `ExecuteProcess` because I want the program to run on both Windows and Linux (at least). I know there are other routines but they're not compatible across different OS.

Comment: A million thanks for your answer! I didn't quite understand the *magic* behind the execute line but it works on my Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop. I am curious though to know how this will be different with Windows or a different OS. Would you be able to enlighten me on that a bit? Cheers!

Comment: Yes. This whole concept is not very portable. E.g. on Windows it depends on if you really need a console allocated or not. I think a convoluted use of portable functions is worse than using non-portable (but clear and to the point) functions. I would use fpsystem on *nix and shellexecute on Windows.

Comment: Thanks again. I've only worked with Windows and Linux. So using fpsystem or shellexceute seem acceptable. But how does this port onto *other* systems like MacsOS and others - Are they the same? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Mac OS X is an unix-like in this regard. OSes that are not Unix-like and not Windows are increasingly rare and peculiar.  It's mostly only DOS and direct derivatives (like dosextenders under OS/2)